# Pandas: substitute commas for points in a column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, substitution

I have a column of values from a csv-file who contain commas instead of points. With the code below I want to turn these into points, however this does  not work.

There is no error message, the code just runs and if I call the column `Betrag()` (german: absolute value) from the dataframe `Umsatz`, it display no change. The commas are still in place.

```
def removecom(value):
value=value.replace(',','.')

Umsatz['Betrag()']=Umsatz['Betrag()'].apply(lambda value: removecom(value))

Umsatz['Betrag()']
```

for instance turn 7,99 into 7.99

Comment: I think you should try `Umsatz['Betrag()'].str.replace(',', '.')`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for your response

Comment: I have added an answer explaining why your current answer doesn't work, along with an example. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see no change is because `removecom` returns nothing. You should return a value from the function like this:

```
def removecom(value):
    return value.replace(',','.')
```

However, a better method I would recommend is using `df.str.replace`:

```
Umsatz['Betrag()'] = Umsatz['Betrag()'].str.replace(',', '.')
```

Demo:

```
In [750]: df
Out[750]: 
      Col1
0  foo,bar
1  abc,def

In [751]: df['Col1'] = df.Col1.str.replace(',', '.')

In [752]: df
Out[752]: 
      Col1
0  foo.bar
1  abc.def
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the advice concerning the function